# Prevent destroying Component/Page when navigating backwards

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a challenge in my app that I need to resolve quick, the thing is I have to prevent the current component from being destroyed when I navigate backwards using `this.location.back();`

Based on my project I have an About Us link in my Login component that navigate to the About component using `this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/about"]);`, in the About component I added the back button that goes back to Login component as I described in the first paragraph. My problem is that the About component is destroyed and I need to prevent that.

Is there any way I can implement this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason you need this view preserved when you navigate back?

Comment: Well, my About component loads some resources from the server and shows them on the page, I don't have a problem if I don't preserve the About component, but I have some others that shows lots of information and I want to preserve them when I hit "< Back" in the ActionBar (this.location.back()).

Comment: Have you thought about caching these resources in a provider class or storing them in a local database?  I'm not sure you can preserve views in Angular 2.